# Custom searching a belongs_to assocation is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord

sorry it may be simple but it's making me bash my head against a wall!

I created my own searches model and controller and having trouble searching  a belongs_to association. I am able to search for has_and_belongs_to_many associations fine but I get zero results for belong_to.

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city

  has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
  has_and_belongs_to_many :goals
end

# models/search.rb
class Search < ApplicationRecord
  def search_users
    users = User.all
# These two work
    users = users.joins(:sports).where("sports.name ILIKE ?", "%#{sports}%") if sports.present?
    users = users.joins(:goals).where("goals.name ILIKE ?", "%#{goals}%") if goals.present?

# This doesn't
    users = users.joins(:city).where("cities.name ILIKE ?", "%#{cities}") if cities.present?

    return users
  end
end

# searches_controller.rb
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @search = Search.new
    @sports = Sport.uniq.pluck(:name)
    @goals = Goal.uniq.pluck(:name)
    @cities = City.uniq.pluck(:name)
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.create(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:sports, :goals, :gyms, :cities)
  end
end
```

and my views:

```
#searches/new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @search do |search| %>
  <%= search.label :sports %>
  <%= search.select :sports, options_for_select(@sports), include_blank: :true %>

  <%= search.label :goals %>
  <%= search.select :goals, options_for_select(@goals), include_blank: :true %>


  <%= search.input :cities, collection: City.all.order(name: :asc), as: :select, label: "City" %>

  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

searches/show.html.erb

```
<% if @search.search_users.empty? %>
  Nothing
<% else %>

  <% @search.search_users.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name %>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Basically when selecting a City from the dropdown list it doesn't register and gives me the empty search condition and I can't figure out why it won't select it. However selecting the sports and/or goals and it gives me the user matching those.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Okay I've managed to get it working by simply changing my dropdown select in my view from:

```
<%= search.input :cities, collection: City.all.order(name: :asc), as: :select, label: "City" %>
```

to this:

```
<%= search.select :cities, options_for_select(@cities) %>
```

**HOWEVER,** I'd still like to know why the other way doesn't work?

Comment: I think `if cities.present?` should be `if city.present?`

Comment: Hey sorry no that gives an undefined variable/method error. I've got cities as the params permitted in my controller. I've added it now, sorry I forgot that!

Comment: yes, just seen that. move `@search.search_users` to controller. Also,
`<%= @search.search_users.each do |user| %>` should be  `<% @search.search_users.each do |user| %>`

Comment: also, `searches/view.html.erb` what is this file?

Comment: Gosh, sorry. I've been really sloppy it's my show.html.erb. In a bit of a rush. Hold on let me clean things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= search.input :cities, collection: City.all.order(name: :asc), as: :select, label: "City" %>
```

One of the reasons the above code didn't work is,

`City.all.order(name: :asc)` return a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, but a collection searches for an `array or range.`

**Collections can be arrays or ranges**. from [the collection documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections)

Another point from that documentaion is,

**when a `:collection` is given the `:select` input will be rendered by default, so we don't need to pass the `as: :select`**

So, change the input to

`<%= search.input :cities, collection: City.uniq.pluck(:name).sort,label: "City" %>`

Comment: That's it. Thank you! Stupidly simple in the end.. May I ask how you then order the list alphabetically name? as that's the main reason I was trying the other way.